# Price change in forecast

Tags: forecasting, forecast-combination

I recently joined a online retail company and the way they have been doing forecasting and inventory management is not good at all and I'm working on improving the forecasting of the products. While working through the data I come across many anomalies with the data being not good for forecast.
How to modify data when there was a price change since that would increase the sale?

Answer (score 1):

incorporate price as a predictor variable . In this way the impact of the price variable will be accounted for in your forecast. Anomaly detection is also very important in forming a useful model. Both causal variables and anomaly detection can be dealt with in both an automatic and non-automatic way.

Answer (score 0):

if there is price change in your company, you can forecast the quantity of products that u will sell in future and multiply the quantity by the up-to-date price of those products and calculate the forecast price.